# How to use Arel::Nodes::TableAlias in an initial where statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel, table-alias

I got stuck on this and for sure it's easy, but I just cannot find the solution in the docs.

I have some tree structure and the child where clause that I have to filter with an "exists" sub query:

```
current_node.children.as("children_nodes").where(Node.where(...).exists)
```

The Node.where.clause already joins to the children_nodes and it works if I use two different models. But how do I use the alias? Above code will result in:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `where' for #<Arel::Nodes::TableAlias
```

It's so basic, but something I'm missing (I'm too new to arel).

Comment: Try with `current_node.children.as("children_nodes").Node.(where(...).exists)` didn't tested though.

Comment: current_node.children.as("children_nodes").Node will give me undefined method Node for #<Arel::Nodes::TableAlias. Maybe you mixed something up?

Answer (score 5):

You might be able to use the attribute `table_alias` which you can call on an Arel::Table.

Example:

```
# works
users = User.arel_table
some_other_table = Post.arel_table
users.table_alias = 'people'
users.join(some_other_table)

# doesn't work
users = User.arel_table.alias('people')
some_other_table = Post.arel_table
users.join(some_other_table)
```

Comment: Warning: the `arel_table` method always returns the same object (at least in Rails 4.2), so changing the `table_alias` has side effects. Using `User.arel_table.dup` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

the as method generate an arel object which doesn't has where method such Relation object
the Arel object generates a sql to be executed basically its a select manager
you can use union and give it another condition then use to_sql
for example:

> arel_obj = current_node.children.as("children_nodes").Union(Node.where(....)
>
> sql_string = arel_obj.to_sql
>
> Node.find_by_sql(sql_string)

here is some links that might help
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel/SelectManager

Answer (score 0):

In Arel, `as` will take everything up to that point and use it to create a named subquery that you can put into a `FROM` clause. For example, `current_node.children.as("children_nodes").to_sql` will print something like this:

```
(SELECT nodes.* FROM nodes WHERE nodes.parent_id = 5) AS children_nodes
```

But it sounds like what you really want is to give a SQL alias to the `nodes` table. Technically you can do that with `from`:

```
current_node.children.from("nodes AS children_nodes").to_sql
```

But if you do that, lots of other things are going to break, because the rest of the query is still trying to `SELECT nodes.*` and filter `WHERE nodes.parent_id = 5`.

So I think a better option is to avoid using an alias, or write your query with `find_by_sql`:

```
Node.find_by_sql <<-EOQ
    SELECT n.*
    FROM   nodes n
    WHERE  n.parent_id = 5
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM   nodes n2
                WHERE  ....)
EOQ
```

Perhaps you could also make things work by aliasing the inner table instead:

```
current_node.children.where(
  Node.from("nodes n").where("...").select("1").exists
)
```